# Why can't open the console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard

Tags: google-apps-script

When I was open the console.developers.google.com, I got the blank page, and I waited a long time. Look:

[image]

In my network, I must use proxy (by shadowsocks or vpn) to visit google.com, and I had tried many times by many ways in many hours, but I can open the other Google service, like google.com, youtube.com.

Maybe the problem is because my network, or other reason?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is the wrong tag for your question....

That said: It seems like its just you:

I tried my own proxy and it looks like it works...
If you want, you can try my proxy, but please do not spam it etc:
coachesoffice.tk <-- is the site link